# Is this valid use of logical implication in an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following:
$$
\mathbf{A}^{-2}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b} 
\Rightarrow
(\mathbf{A}^{-2}\mathbf{A})\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
\Rightarrow
\mathbf{I}_3\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
\Rightarrow
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
$$
All equations are equivalent and thus the one implies the other. Now in that sentence, both "equivalent" and "imply" are present. So I could use $\Leftrightarrow$ for the equivalence
$$
\mathbf{A}^{-2}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b} 
\Leftrightarrow
(\mathbf{A}^{-2}\mathbf{A})\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
\Leftrightarrow
\mathbf{I}_3\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
\Leftrightarrow
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
$$
 or I could use $\Rightarrow$ for the fact that one implies the other or I could maybe just use $=$ only
$$
\mathbf{A}^{-2}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b} 
=
(\mathbf{A}^{-2}\mathbf{A})\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
=
\mathbf{I}_3\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
=
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}
$$
. This is my ideas but I do not know which one is correct (I actually hope the use of $\Rightarrow$ is correct because that would save me from some trouble :) ).

So I reach out to some of you wizards to give me advice on which one to use and if I did it correct (using $\Rightarrow$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol $\implies$ means "implies" so $p\implies q$ means that if $p$ is true, then $q$ is true. If we have $p$ implies $q$ and $q$ implies $p$ at the same time, then $p$ and $q$ are logically equivalent, since one is true exactly when the other is true. Your first chain of logical deductions is correct but different from the second one (which is also correct), since they say different things. On the other hand, the statement with all $=$s is wrong, because the $=$ sign denotes that the numerical expressions are the same, not that the logical propositions are equivalent (which seems to be the heart of your confusion here).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in each case if equivalence holds.

For instance, you may write

$$x=1\implies x^2=1$$ but not $$x=1\iff x^2=1.$$